# Translation of "so + adj."

Tags: adjectifs, adverbes

I am wondering how to translate the construction"so + adj." to French. Take the following sentences for example.

He works so hard. 
We are so far apart. 
The water is so cold.

Also, what kind of word is "so" in this case? Is it an adverb?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most neutral translation is [***tellement***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tellement).

> *Il travaille tellement dur !*   (He works so hard!)
>   *Nous sommes tellement éloignés !*   (We are so far apart!)
>   *L'eau est tellement froide !*   (The water is so cold!)
>   *J'en ai vu tellement !*   or   *J'en ai vu tant !*   (I've seen so many!)
>   *J'en ai vu tellement peu !*   (I've seen so few!)

When *so* qualifies an adjective (including *peu*), you can use ***si*** instead of *tellement*. Using *si* in this context is somewhat uncommon in spoken French these days, but still common in literary French. You can't use *si* without an adjective after it to express a large amount, but you can use *tant*. When it's followed by an adverb, *si* is more common than *tellement* except a few adverbs that don't end in *-ment* (*bien*, *mal*, but not *vite* which prefers *si*).

> *Il l'a accueillie si froidement !*   (He greeted her so coldly!)
>   *Un accident est si vite arrivé.*   (lit. “An accident can happen so quickly”; used to highlight the risk of an accident, i.e. the likelihood that an accident happens, not the speed at which an accident happens)
>   *C'est tellement mal conçu !*   (This is so badly designed!)

For “so … that …”, French uses a similar construction: “*tellement … que …*” or “*si … que …*”. Here *si* is common even in spoken French. Here too, you can't use *si* without an adjective; *tant que* is possible.

> *Il travaille tellement/si dur qu'on fait tout pour le garder.*   (He works so hard that we do everything we can to keep him.)
>   *C'est tellement mal conçu que la plupart des gens renoncent.*   (This is so badly designed that most people give up.)
>   *J'en ai vu tellement/tant que je suis blasé.*   (I've seen so many that I'm jaded.)
>   *J'en ai vu tellement peu que je ne me souviens plus à quoi ils ressemblent.*   (I've seen so few that I don't remember what they look like.)

Answer (score 13):

It can be translated with "si + adj." (or "tellement + adj." sometimes).

"Si" is a quantity / comparison / intensity adverb here.

In your examples: Il travaille si dur. Nous sommes si éloignés. L'eau est si froide

Comment: Nice. One note to add and one question. Note: "so" in English has the same status (adverb), in case there was any doubt. :) Question: in English, you can also say "He worked so hard *that* ... some result happened." Can both of these French words fill that rule? I think only *si* can but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: It's working in French with "si ... que" or "tellement ... que" as well. I think that "si" is more frequent but both are correct

Comment: @ThomasWening Remember that "so + adj" is very popular in English but "si + adj" sounds kind of aged. Especially among young people it's rather rare.

Comment: @Teleporting Goat I don't agree that Si + Adjective is rare. I don't even understand what that means. L'eau était si froide que je ne me suis pas baignée. Ça fait parole de vieux, ça? Ou dois-je dire de vielle? Le pain était si dur que personne en a mangé.

Comment: @Lambie D'une, il y a une différence d'usage entre "si ... que ..." et juste "si + adj". De deux, oui, si on veut (*no offense* ^^ (et pas *ta phrase* en particulier, je parle de "*si + adj*" en général )). Jamais quand je mange un burger je me dis "C'est si bon !" En fait c'est surtout que le "so + adj" est surutilisé en anglais en ce moment, surtout par les jeunes. Je tiens à souligner que "si" est pas un bon équivalent à ça, parce que je vois souvent l'erreur.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais parlé de l'anglais. Je parlais de ton commentaire: but "si + adj" sounds kind of aged." Et je ne parlais pas non plus de phrases comme: C'est si bon. Par ailleurs, détrompe-toi, les so good, so interesting etc. ont toujours fait partie du language courant de tout le monde. The movie was so good, the food was so good. Ce qui est sûr, par contre, c'est que les jeunes commencent les phrases avec so. Ça oui et surutilisent le so comme ceci: they were so playing the guitar. So + verbe. :) They were so laughing at him. Ce qui est un erreur de language mais acceptable comme argot.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively *vachement* is a more slangy but popular term, as in *c'est vachement chouette*, it's so awesome. Or you might say *super*, as in *c'est super cool*.

Answer (score 1):

Orally, we mostly use "très" ( very ) and "si" for exclamation ( but we really don't use a lot of exclamation unlike the english did with "so")

http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tr%C3%A8s/79444

> C'est très simple. Cela se produit très souvent. Il est très en
>   colère. Il fait très froid. J'ai très faim.

```
Nous sommes très éloignés ( but here "si" is better for me according to how far you are, even orally )
```

And for "The water is so cold", we can say "L'eau est très froide" or "L'eau est gelé" ( gelé = frozen )